# Resize UIImage without squashing

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, resize, uiimage

I would like to resize a UIImage to be able to upload it to parse.com. I would like to resize it without squashing it. How can I make sure that it is small enough to upload to parse.com (10485760 bytes) but not squash it to a set size.
This is the code I tried below but obviously sets the image size exactly.
Any ideas?

```
    var newSize:CGSize = CGSize(width: 600,height: 600)
    let rect = CGRectMake(0,0, newSize.width, newSize.height)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 0.0)

    // image is a variable of type UIImage
    profileImage?.drawInRect(rect)

    profileImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using this method to scale your image while maintaining the aspect ratio:

```
func scaleImage(image: UIImage, maxDimension: CGFloat) -> UIImage {

    var scaledSize = CGSize(width: maxDimension, height: maxDimension)
    var scaleFactor: CGFloat

    if image.size.width > image.size.height {
        scaleFactor = image.size.height / image.size.width
        scaledSize.width = maxDimension
        scaledSize.height = scaledSize.width * scaleFactor
    } else {
        scaleFactor = image.size.width / image.size.height
        scaledSize.height = maxDimension
        scaledSize.width = scaledSize.height * scaleFactor
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(scaledSize)
    image.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, scaledSize.width, scaledSize.height))
    let scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return scaledImage
}
```

In this case, you would call it like so:

```
profileImage = scaleImage(profileImage, newSize: CGSizeMake(600, 600))
```